# Cash On Delivery payment method not showing in checkout page in magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1.9

Cash On delivery payment method not showing in the frontend.

I have enabled the offline payment methods in the backend, It shows all offline payment methods in frontend except COD. Please provide me a solution

[image]

Comment: Please check storewise setting for payment method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check store view/ website view**

[image]

```
php bin/magento c:f
```