# Cash on delivery not showing on payment page in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, php-7.2, cash-on-delivery

Cash on delivery payment method not showing on the payment page. I have enabled it from backend but it's still not showing. All Other payment methods are working except COD. I have gone through this solution [Cash On Delivery payment method not showing in checkout page in magento 2.1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245686/cash-on-delivery-payment-method-not-showing-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2-1-9)  also but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have simple product or configurable or downloadable product ?
because, COD will not show in downloadable or virtual product.
Just check and let me know.

Comment: I have only simple and configurable products. I tried disabling other payment methods also but it's not working by doing this also. @bharat desai